# Why is handlerReturnValue undefined in my scenario?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a table bound to an observable array.

I iterate over each item and create a table row.

Each element of the array has a property called `keypress`, which is a function that verifies the key pressed is numeric (or decimal point).

In each row, I bind an input control's event to the item's `keypress` property and the code executes as expected.

After the code exits the property with the appropriate value, the result is evaluated in knoclout-3.1.0.debug.js in the "ko.bindingHandlers event object (line 3092 and following).

Even though I've tried returning both true and the event's `charCode` value on different occasions, in both cases line 3108 fails to evaluate the handlerReturnValue properly, and when the finally block is executed, the handlerReturnValue evaluates to undefined, causing the event.preventDefault() method to execute and my keystroke is cancelled, even though it was valid. The HTML for the input looks like this:

```
<input type="number"  data-bind="value: currentValue, event: { keypress: function(data, event) { keypress(event, data) } }"/>
```

this is what each item looks like (scaled down):

```
var obj = { keypress: function (data, event) { 
    if (isNumberKeyDec(event)) { 
         return true; 
    } else { 
         return false; 
    }
 }};
```

I also tried returning `event.charCode` instead of true and in both cases the keystroke still gets cancelled

Any thoughts on why `handlerReturnValue` is undefined and thus preventing my proper keystrokes from being executed?

Comment: Does every row require its own keypress event or do you just need for each row to be wired into a `keypress` event?  IOW -- could you reuse the same keypress code across all rows if they were wired up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your binding to this:

```
event: { keypress: function(data, event) { return keypress(event, data) } }
```

Comment: adding return was the answer! Thanks so much, Michael! You're the best! :)